# Check if an Android app is installed via Play Store production or test track

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to determine at runtime if an Android app is installed through a Play Store production track or through a testing track (closed, internal or open, it doesn't matter).

On iOS we can determine if a release build is installed through the Store or through TestFlight at runtime, I'm looking for something similar but for production/test tracks on Play Store.

Comment: any luck with finding an answer to this?

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately, no

Comment: @andrew_b or Andrew did any of you find anything by now?